# Download GCS bucket blob with a question mark in it to file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am encountering a weird error, that I suspect is caused by a question mark in my file. I have redacted the URIs a bit but you get the idea.

This works:
`gsutil cp gs://bucket-id/209146000/showphoto.aspx?photoid=12345.jpg test.jpg`

But this:

`client.download_blob_to_file('gs://bucket-id/209146000/showphoto.aspx?photoid=12345.jpg', open('test.jpg', 'wb'))`

Gives me an error:

`NotFound: 404 GET https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/marine-scrape/o/209146000%2Fshowphoto.aspx?alt=media: ('Request failed with status code', 404, 'Expected one of', <HTTPStatus.OK: 200>, <HTTPStatus.PARTIAL_CONTENT: 206>)`

How do I avoid this? I probably should not have used the ? mark in the filename in the first place, but here we are. I have tried escaping it `\?` but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer has two solutions.

**Rename the object with the problem filename**

1. Login to the Google Cloud Console.
2. Go to Storage.
3. Select the bucket containing the file.
4. Select the folder containing the object.
5. On the far right side of the object, is the ellipse menu.
6. Click this menu and select Rename.
7. Rename the object.

**Change the code**

I reviewed the source code for the library `google.cloud.storage` version 1.20.0. The function `download_blob_to_file()` does not support URL encoding when the first parameter is a string. It does work for `blob` objects. I am including two different methods that support your filenames.

**Method 1:**

```
import  sys
import urllib.parse

# Imports the Google Cloud client library
from google.cloud import storage

bucket_name = 'bucket-id'
object_name = '209146000/showphoto.aspx?photoid=12345.jpg'
outfile = 'test.jpg'

client = storage.Client()

bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket_name)

blob = storage.Blob(object_name, bucket)

client.download_blob_to_file(blob, open('test.jpg', 'wb'))
```

**Method 2:**

```
import  sys
from google.cloud import storage

bucket_name = 'bucket-id'
object_name = '209146000/showphoto.aspx?photoid=12345.jpg'
outfile = 'test.jpg'

client = storage.Client()

bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket_name)

blob = bucket.blob(object_name)

blob.download_to_filename(outfile)
```

Comment: Tried your second suggestion and using Python 3.7 unfortunately got the same error @Gerard did. But perhaps someone has a different result?

Comment: Update: same issue using Python 2.7.

Comment: @Maxim - I updated my answer with Python 3 code that I tested.

Comment: Thank you, have not tried the code, but I appreciate the work around. What I personally end up doing to rename them programatically is to use ipython to issue `gsutil mv` commands for each file with a question mark.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look on this [Bucket and object naming guidelines](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/naming#objectnames) you will find that you must avoid using special characters such  "[", "]", "*", or "?" in your object names.

To avoid this just dont use special characters when naming your buckets or your objects.

From here you can just rename your files

Comment: What do you mean by _from here_ exactly?

Comment: From here = In your actual situation

Answer (score 0):

Those characters are permitted in GCS object names; it is gsutil that is interpreting them as wildcards, and thus preventing you from downloading the object.

Renaming so you don't use those characters would make it so gsutil doesn't have this problem for you, but if that's not possible you could use another tool to download the object (e.g., wget). There's a long-open [bug](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/issues/220) against gsutil to support a raw mode to address this problem, but the bug is still open.